# jekyll-assets: scss.liquid file not working with @import

Tags: jekyll, liquid

In order to render a background image dynamically, I have a piece of SCSS that looks like this:

```
my-div {
  background-image: url(asset_path('img_name.png'));
}
```

However, what I'd like to do is use a .yml file to import that background image dynamically. I imagine it would look like this:

```
my-div {
  background-image: url(asset_path('{{ site.data.directory.background_image }}'));
}

//directory.yml
background_image: img_name.png
```

Doing so requires that I preprocess my scss file. In order to do that, jekyll-assets requires that I append the .liquid file type to the .scss file so that it will render all the liquid tags within. However, doing such causes an error, because @import cannot find .liquid files.

```
//styles.scss.liquid
my-div {
  ...
 }

//main.scss
@import "styles"

error: File to import not found or unreadable: styles
```

Alternatively, if I try to import:
`@import "styles.scss.liquid"` I get the same issue.

What is the correct approach to getting the liquid preprocessor to both be imported and used?

Answer (score 1):

You should be using Sprokets to require anything that is processed using Sprockets asset pipeline, Sprockets does not directly integrate with SASS in that manner, and neither does Jekyll-Assets. The following should work:

```
//= require ./styles.scss.liquid
body {
  // My Styles
}
```